# Adding group id dynamically in jbpm

Tags: jbpm, business-process-management

I want to add group id dynamically in jbpm. I know that Actor Id can be added dynamically using a variable with the format #{employee}. I cannot apply the same to the group id. How this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

GroupId should be similar to other task parameters, so I believe this should work.
Could you create a JIRA issue and attach a reproducer?